# Create a view in a schema in QGIS DB Manager

Tags: qgis, postgis, dbmanager

When I have created a query in the DBManager window of QGIS I want to save it as a view. When I click on the `Create a view` button, I'm then prompted for a name.

This is all fine, **but** I want to create my view in a schema - so I type `general.view_1` in the name box. This doesn't create a view called `view_` in the `general` schema but a view called `general.view_1` in the `public` schema.

Is this a bug? a feature? or am I missing something obvious?

Comment: You can try putting `general` as the 1st schema in your PG user search path.

Answer (score 2):

1. You can manually move the view using `Menu Table > Move to Schema ...`

   or
2. Create the view directy in the correct schema defining it in the query like `create view general.view1 as SELECT ...`

Comment: I know I can fix it after, but I'd like it to go to my prefered location directly from the `create view` button

Comment: Well, then probably the second option to directly create the view with the query seems to be the only option. The `Create a view` button indeed does not allow to enter a schema, just a name for the view which is then saved by default to the public schema.